# Wordpress SSL 404 and redirect

Tags: wordpress, ssl, wordpress-login

I'm running WP 3.8 for a client site on an Apache server. I have installed an SSL cert that my client purchased from GoDaddy. I am able to verify that the SSL is installed properly, by creating a test php page in the root directory and visiting it on https. It works.

The problem is, no pages inside Wordpress work with SSL. Visiting the homepage - https://assembliesofyahweh.com - redirects to the host's homepage. Visiting any other pages, such as https://assembliesofyahweh.com/contact, result in a 404.

All I need SSL for is the login page. When I add the following:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
```

to my `wp-config` file, the login page itself doesn't redirect to https. Instead, visiting the `wp-admin` page redirects to the https login page and results in a 404.

I have `mod_rewrite` installed and enabled, and Apache is configured to `AllowOverride`. I've looked everywhere, but I haven't found a problem that fits mine. What on Earth am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement it on wp side. You can use [Wordpress HTTPs](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) plugin for this .After install this plugin,

[image]

For some cases, you may need to use ssl on your custom pages(donate page, checkout page, etc). In such cases, you can enable ssl on page edit section like below;

[image].

If you couldn't make it work, please double check your **WordPress Address (URL)** from admin panel **Settings > General**. Give your https domain there;

[image]

Now, you can use your page in https

Comment: Thanks, but I installed the plugin and the errors are all still the same. I chose to 'force SSL exclusively', then used the sidebar option on a few of my pages to see what would happen. They all resulted in 404's.

Comment: Are you able to open your http site?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean I can visit the site over http and everything works? If so, then yes. It all works fine.

Comment: Could you please also set WordPress Address (URL) in Admin panel Settings > General as your https domain? I have stated it in my updated answer

Comment: But won't that change the entire site to SSL? I don't want to do that - I only want the login page to use SSL.

Comment: By the way, in plugin I mentioned above, could you please check Force SSL Administration ? It is working for me

Comment: Checking Force SSL Administration would lock me out of the dashboard - I've already tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem (404 errors when accessing any URL on my website via HTTPS) and the solution for me was to add these lines to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`, which is my SSL-enabled website's configuration file:

```
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```

Of course, this assumes `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`. Change accordingly if is this is different in your setup.

The thing is that Wordpress uses .`htaccess` rules to process the URLs, and for them to work, `AllowOverride All` needs to be in the server's configuration file.

In my situation, the configuration for the non-SSL and SSL-enabled variants were in a separate files. The non-SSL configuration had `AllowOverride All` all along, and so everything was working fine. Once I had enabled the SSL, the other configuration file came into play and didn't have the required `AllowOverride All` setting.